# Selecting record based on time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a model `A` which uses Rails timestamps and a attribute called `ttl` which represents the time in minutes between each update of the record.

I want to select all records that should be updated ergo:

```
WHERE (Time.now - updated_at).to_minutes > ttl)
```

I've been trying to use variations of `Feed.where("(?-updated_at) > ttl", Time.now).to_a` but I've not succeeded yet. Can someone help me with the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is, that databases can't do time calculations just like arithmetic calculations.
You have to use the time function of the DB, unfortunately there is no standard.

In MySQL you could use

```
Feed.where("TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE,ttl,updated_at)<?",Time.now)
```

Comment: Abit annoying to have to use mysql in dev but it works like a charm

Comment: well using `SQLite` you can use `where("strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s',updated_at,'+'||ttl||' minutes') <?",Time.now)` and you can switch between both versions using Rails.env.development? As I said: unfortunately time functions are DB dependend.